# Rank issue with spdiags in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am currently trying to create a sparse matrix that will look like this.

```
[[ 50. -25.   0.   0.]
 [-25.  50. -25.   0.]
 [  0. -25.  50. -25.]
 [  0.   0. -25.  50.]]
```

But when I run it through I keep getting the value error

> 'data array must have rank 2'  in my data array.

I am positive it is a problem with my B variable. I have tried several things but nothing is working. Any advice?

```
    def sparse(a,b,N):
        h = (b-a)/(N+1)
        e = np.ones([N,1])/h**2
        B = np.array([e, -2*e, e])
        diags = np.array([-1,0,1])
        A = spdiags(B,diags,N,N).toarray()
        return A
    
    print(sparse(0,1,4))
```

Comment: So does it need to be a sparse matrix?

Comment: Correct I am creating a sparse matrix. Sorry, I should of added that in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import spdiags


def sparse(a, b, N):
    h = (b - a) / (N + 1)
    e = np.ones(N) / h ** 2
    diags = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
    A = spdiags([-1 * e, 2 * e, -1 * e], diags, N, N).toarray()
    return A


print(sparse(0, 1, 4))
```

**Output**

```
[[-50.  25.   0.   0.]
 [ 25. -50.  25.   0.]
 [  0.  25. -50.  25.]
 [  0.   0.  25. -50.]]
```

The main change is this:

```
e = np.ones([N,1])/h**2
```

by

```
e = np.ones(N) / h ** 2
```

Note that [toarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.toarray.html#scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.toarray) transforms the sparse matrix into a dense one, from the documentation:

> Return a dense ndarray representation of this matrix.

Comment: @JoeyHoward988 I added a note with respect to the matrix being sparse